# Finding top 10 in a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) with approx 800 rows with data like this:

Name:Jason
Age: 45
Ticket:1

Name:Kim
Age: 30
Ticket:0

1 = has a ticket
0 = does not have a ticket

***(sorry, that didn't format very well. It's basically 3 columns in the dataframe: Name, Age and Ticket)***

Using Pandas, I am wondering what the syntax is for find the Top 10 oldest people who HAVE a ticket

So far I have:

```
df.sort_values('Age',ascending=False,inplace=True)(data.Ticket==1)
(data.head(10))
```

I know that's not correct but it shows what the parameters are that I am looking for.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you only want names of the old people,then

```
df[df['Ticket'] == 1].sort_values('Age')['Names'].head(10)
```

Comment: Thank you both.  Both of those solutions ran, and they are sorting by Age descending (which is what I want) but neither of them are limiting the dataset to 10 rows. Hmmmm

Comment: sorry bigbounty, it only let me upvote the first one for some reason

Comment: @JD2775 I just up voted your question.  You now have 15 reputation and can upvote.

Comment: And Plus one from me.

Comment: Ha, thanks guys.  Newbie probs.  So, no idea why the returning list isn't stopping at 10?  (see my first reply to the answers)

Comment: Oh ...try doing indexing df[:,:10]

Answer (score 26):

One of the common ways to do this is to use **[nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) method**:

```
df[df.Ticket == 1].nlargest(10, 'Age')['Names']
```

This way you don't need to do sorting explicitly

Answer (score 5):

mask, sort, head

```
df[df.Ticket == 1].sort_values('Age').head(10)
```