# How to set limit to column values on python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas and matplotlib on jupyter notebook. I'm working on the top ranked universities in the world, but it lists almost 2000 values, but I only want to find the top 10. How do I do that? This is the `df.tail()`:

[image]

Comment: df.head(10) ?  to get rows top 10

Comment: Assuming they are sorted in score order, you would use the `.head`, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding top 10 in a dataframe in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859416/finding-top-10-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the dataframe to include only the top 10 schools, I would first [sort by ranking](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ranking'])
```

Then index the top 10 rows:

```
df_topten = df.iloc[:10]
```